# encoding data using json

Tags: json, zend-framework2

am pretty new to json and i have this data that i would like to pass to a view script..the data comes from an sql query i have executed as below:

```
                    public function get_specific_users($param)
 {
    $select=new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
    $select->from('users');
       $select->columns(array('username','password','firstname','lastname','reputation'));
    $select->where(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('username',$param. "%"));
    $resultSet=$this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
    return $resultSet;
}
```

this is how i call the function from my controller:

```
                  $users=$this->getUserTable()->get_specific_users('jo');


     return new JsonModel(array('data' =>$users));
```

can i be able to pass the $users as above or should i first convert the resultset to  an array..?if not how can i go about it..thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay..i did more research and got it..had to include the following:

```
                $users=$this->getUserTable()->get_specific_users('jo');
         $result = \Zend\Json\Json::encode($users);
         return $result;
```

the output was pretty clean json data which i can now  parse using jquery..